# UICollectionView glitches on scroll

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, contacts

I am implementing UICollectionView for loading all the contact information on the screen. Keeping the main and the background threads clean, I am loading the data on the collectionview. Now as soon as the data is loaded and I start scrolling, it give me an extreme lag/jitter of frames. I am not sure why this is happening. All my datasourcing in on the background thread.

below is the code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let data : PhoneContact!
    data = allContacts[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: friendsCellID, for: indexPath) as! FriendsCell
    cell.label.text = data.name
    return cell
}

// Cell has only label
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: (r: 232, g: 231, b: 222))
    setLabel()
}
```

`allContact` has a getter that everytime fetches the contacts from the phone book. I guess this might be an issue. But not sure. Can I have some eyes on it? I think I am not thinking about something and ending up with an erroneous result.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a `UICollectionViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`. If you used a `UITableViewController`, you could try implementing the `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` delegate to handle long-running operations, but I don't think that's what's happening here.

If you're dequeuing a cell from the collection view in a storyboard, the you should *not* have an initializer for it. Instead, since all you're doing in the initializer is setting up a label and a background color, this should be done in the storyboard, and an outlet should be connected between the cell to its label.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Edited the question. Plus, It doesnt have story boards. Its all programmatically.